# set a factor to just one level only

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to set every instance of a factor variable to a constant factor level, but retain knowledge of the other, not present, levels. So:

```
pp.df<-data.frame(c(1:10))
for (itype in 1:4){
    pp.df$TYPE<-itype
    pp.df$TYPE<-as.factor(pp.df$TYPE)
    levels(pp.df$TYPE)<-c("T","D","F","S")
    print(summary(pp.df$TYPE))
}
```

produces:

```
 T  D  F  S 
10  0  0  0 
 T  D  F  S 
10  0  0  0 
 T  D  F  S 
10  0  0  0 
 T  D  F  S 
10  0  0  0
```

whilst the desired output is:

```
 T  D  F  S 
10  0  0  0 
 T  D  F  S 
 0 10  0  0 
 T  D  F  S 
 0  0 10  0 
 T  D  F  S 
 0  0  0 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

```
pp.df<-data.frame(c(1:10))
for (itype in c("T","D","F","S")){
  pp.df$TYPE<-itype
  pp.df$TYPE<-factor(pp.df$TYPE,levels=c("T","D","F","S"))
  #levels(pp.df$TYPE)<-c("T","D","F","S")
  print(summary(pp.df$TYPE))
}

T  D  F  S 
10  0  0  0 
 T  D  F  S 
 0 10  0  0 
 T  D  F  S 
 0  0 10  0 
 T  D  F  S 
 0  0  0 10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pp.df<-data.frame(c(1:10))
for (itype in 1:4){
    pp.df$TYPE<-itype

    # need to build the facotr with 4 levels to start with
    pp.df$TYPE<-factor(pp.df$TYPE, levels=1:4)
    levels(pp.df$TYPE)<-c("T","D","F","S")
    print(summary(pp.df$TYPE))
                    }
```

Should also realize that pp.df will not have all those values after this process:

```
> pp.df
   c.1.10. TYPE
1        1    S
2        2    S
3        3    S
4        4    S
5        5    S
6        6    S
7        7    S
8        8    S
9        9    S
10      10    S
```

If that's what you wanted, fine. If not, you should describe what was needed in natural language.